# Since 10 years, did I setup my web server wrong?

Tags: linux, nginx, php, domain-name, user-permissions

**Before story:**
We had a vserver with a domain around year 2004-2007 with apache. My father was owner and I was learning little bit from his friend (he was doing that stuff). I learned how to use linux via putty. I think we used there a system which was called confixx. There we had a linux user account which was "web1" there in /home folder with a html folder in it and all web stuff was there.

These days I use nginx and if I read articles they write always about "/var/www/" and "www-data" user. I even found an article which writes about www/web1 www/web2. It makes sense for me because sometimes I even have permission problems. Example if I upload file via php script it cannot move file because it belongs to www-data ( even if web1 has www-data group). I needed to change php config to that username.

**How I do my setup:**
Most time a vserver comes with a crazy domain like vserver1234.yourniceserver.com. I create subdomain or normal domain and the root html is under

- /home/web1/sites/nameofthedomain/html
- /home/web1/sites/nameofthedomain/subdomain/name/html
- /home/web2/html *its a special single domain.*

I use my vserver most time to test things around, for own written fileshare system and wordpress-blog.

So the question is:

- Did I all these years wrong?
- Should I move that to "/var/www" folder?

  - If yes, it possible to use to create web1 user or need these folders to be owner of root? Because every user like web1, web2 can use ftp.

Edit: I use debian.

Comment: "Wrong" in this case is not the correct term. You could say that your config differs from various defaults or "best practices", but it's not _wrong_ wrong. If you have one webserver and can use one user/group, just go with the defaults (`/var/www` and `www-data`), I believe it's massively simpler than different users and directories (e.g. the permissions). But you do you.

Comment: `/var/www` is a convention (cf. Debian's [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)). You'll have permission problems, whether it is `/var/www` or `/home`. A simple solution is to set all directories `setgid` and use an appropriate `umask` (like `007`).

Answer (score 2):

If you follow [FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf) closely, then from that you can decipher that `/srv/www/example.com` is the most appropriate of all. Despite being the least popular.

Appropriate, maybe not practical, however.

If you're working with CentOS/RHEL or other Fedora-based systems and intend to keep SELinux enabled, then, simply to match up with existing file context locations `/var/www/html/example.com` is most practical.

So e.g. if you put a Wordpress instance at `/var/www/html/example.com`, then it will work correctly without having to disable SELinux, because the files will have correct labels.

On RHEL 8 system, `semanage fcontext -l | grep wp-` yields:

```
...
/var/www/html(/.*)?/wp-content(/.*)?               all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 
...
```

So the standard SELinux has "expectation" of files placed in either `/var/www/html` (single site per server) or `/var/www/html/example.com` (multiple websites on server).

However, as a personal preference, I would still stick to `/srv/www/example.com` and add the correct labeling with, e.g. `semanage fcontext -a ...`

Answer (score 0):

Your config is not specifically "wrong" (as in "it will not work"), but is definitely less than ideal; you are placing web server files and data in what is essentially a user home directory.

Sort of like if in Windows you placed your website root under `C:\Users\Someone\wwwroot` instead of `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` (or any more appropriate place, such as a dedicated data disk).

There isn't any practical difference for a single small web site, but nobody would use such a setup in a real web server.